# MongoDB Spring Data - Sort by Referenced object property

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I search a lot trying to do what I want to do and can't find a solution. Can anyone help me?

I have two Mongo Collections:

A. Post

```
{
    content: "...",
    user: {
        $ref: "user",
        $id: ObjectId(...)
    }
}
```

B. User

```
{
    name: "user name",
    age: 21
}
```

And I want to list all the posts sorted by User name, can I do it?

I tried something like that:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.with(new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "user.name")));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Post.class);
```

But doesn't work, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is only a document store by design, you can use it like a relational DB, if you have to something like this, either

- MongoDB is not for you
- Or you need get both collections and join them manuell

Comment: I use SQL and Mongo together in my application. For this data I use mongo and divide in two collections for some reasons, and now I need to search/sort post by user properties

Comment: @daymannovaes you are doing is `JOIN`, which is not for MongoDB, hope you realize that ;)

Comment: @daymannovaes basically you need fetch data from two collections separately, depends on the data amount, you can optimize it whatever you like

Answer (score 0):

With this schema you can't sort posts by user name in one atomic operation.
You have some choices:

1. Use user names in field **user** and make sure that you have index on field **name** in users colection, so you can sort posts by user names in one operation and you will increase performance by using indexes.
2. If you don't want to change schema, so try to use mongo aggregation framework.